# Share HTML5 player on Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a player both in Flash as well the same in HTML5 version. I am calling a page through iframe which detects the browser and device and loads the player accordingly and it is working fine.

Before the HTML5 version of the player I was able to share the Flash player to Facebook. But how do we make it workable with HTML5 player? If I share the iframe page it doesn't work nor the video doesn't play.

I find that youtube is able to do the same what we require, please advice and help how to accomplish the requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Check the section corresponding to audio and video data on the [open graph documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

You will need to add the following open graph tags to the resource page as given in the documentation.

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> 
    <head>
        ...
        [REQUIRED TAGS]
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" 
              content="https://secure.example.com/awesome.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/html5.mp4" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/fallback.vid" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
        ...
    </head>
```

Comment: Thanks Jai :)
I want to post the customized HTML5 player to Facebook not the video only as I am able to post for the flash player and it plays the videos inside in Facebook wall. Can you please help me what changes I have to do to accomplish the requirements.

Comment: @Jeetendra I don't think custom HTML5 video player is supported as of now.

Comment: @JaiPandya thanks for you answer Jai! If I could mark you as an answer I would!

Comment: @JaiPandya do you know if Facebook has added support for html5 custom players already?

Comment: @Jai How is YouTube doing it then?

Comment: I know for a fact that YouTube, Vimeo, and possibly other video platforms, do it. How come it is only possible for them ?