# Open Graph iframe based video embed support?

Tags: facebook, iframe, embed, html5-video, facebook-opengraph

I want to be able to serve an iframe video player to the Facebook newsfeed & timeline.

I am aware that it is possible to specify multiple og:video:type properties for different video formats to appear within the newsfeed/timeline.

e.g. an implementation such as
[Share HTML5 player on Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708233/share-html5-player-on-facebook-wall)

As of April last year I believe we also wouldn't need whitelisting, though some kind of whitelisting may be possible for a video type of text/html which isn't generally available.

If we were just serving free video within an iframe it would be quite easy to just grab the flash and mp4 components and include them within Open Graph tags.

However our player is a little more complex, serving content based upon login status, and that level of complexity is likely to increase.

Complexity?

Built in shopping cart - Reviews - Delivery of premium content - micropayments/tipjar

We have quite a flexible oembed implementation
http://www.uqast.com/andy/video-seo?w=640&h=360&aplay=0&affid=0&links=2
Which can return quite clean embed code suitable for the timeline

http://www.uqast.com/services/oembed/?url=http%3A//www.uqast.com/andy/video-seo&w=640&h=360&aplay=0&affid=0&links=2&format=json

We can also quite happily serve the iframe from https if required.

We are also looking towards serving various kinds of HTML5 within the iframe... videos/docs/audio etc

So what procedure do you have to follow to be able to use text/html as a video type and have it whitelisted?

Note: I am the Product Manager for uqast.com

Answer (score 9):

I realise this is an old question, but I noticed today (June 2014) that SoundCloud are now embedding an IFRAME HTML based player directly into the news feed.

Anyone else noticed this behaviour and how can they do it? Couldn't see anything in the OG tags about it

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Its not currently possible to embed HTML5 content via an iframe in the Facebook News Feed. Only Flash objects or raw video files can be embedded through the og:video tag.

However, keep an eye on http://developers.facebook.com/blog for updates.

Comment: Hi Simon - thanks for the response "from the horses mouth".

You have this on your profile

" I also work with startups and other companies to help them build Facebook integrations that don't suck, and work awesomely"

We are just trying to have a Facebook implementation that doesn't suck for our users.

Comment: html5 embeds would be nice... ;-)

Comment: @SimonCross — any update on this in Sept 2015? It appears Vimeo and a few other OVPs are now being displayed as html5 iframes.

Comment: @SimonCross - I noticed today that Interlude based videos can be played in the user's status post.  I too would love to figure this out.