# Facebook wall post swf with node.js connection

Tags: facebook, node.js, flash

Reading the The Open Graph protocol site > http://ogp.me/ for reference.

```html
<meta property="og:video:secure_url"content="https://www.example.com/my.swf?v=1"/> 
<meta name="og:video:height"content="164"/> 
<meta name="og:video:width"content="164"/>
<meta name="og:video:type"content="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

It looks like I would need to whitelist http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=video_embed_whitelist because of my using https

I take it that Facebook allow SWF players for video wrappers from all of the talk in forums i have seen, although I have not seen any non-standard/custom video players being embedded on a Facebook wall post.

To wall post a custom swf video it looks like i would have to:

1. make a facebook app
2. make a html *page to hold the swf with the open graph meta tags shown above
3. post a status update with the link to the *page

Now for the tricky part of this question...

I use Node.js (particularly Socket.io) and rather than make lots and lots of SWF files I want to make one SWF that connects to get the video (this could be done with a flashvar like v=1), **But I am wondering would Facebook block this server connection?**

If this is possible I was looking at this: http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2008/11/29/flash-socket-bridge-with-haxe/ But I am also not so sure - although this code looks like node it seems now that I've had a coffee it's only client side. Also I am unfamiliar with swf/flex/flash/wtf and was wondering while reading a lot of different flash javascript bridge code on various websites if this all is even possible with a simple swf or are they talking about air?

Does anyone know of a javascript library / flash library that could connect to node.js, socket.io or some other module? I feel I am going mostly on theory here, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Create the content as follows in your node.js file.

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="1;url=http://www.xyz.com/">
    <meta property="og:title" content="HERE GOES THE VIDEO TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="HERE GOES THE VIDEO DESCRIPTION" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="HERE GOES THE PATH OF VIDEO THUMBNAIL" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="HERE GOES THE SECURED PATH OF VIDEO THUMBNAIL" />

    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="HERE GOES THE PATH OF VIDEO FLV PATH" />
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="HERE GOES THE PATH OF VIDEO SECURED PATH" />
    <meta name="og:video:height" content="303" />
    <meta name="og:video:width" content="404" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Then you need to call this file through sharer.php file as below in url in encoded format

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[url encoded format pointing to that file with parameters if any]

Comment: From my past knowledge and experience. You can also look into this post : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708233/share-html5-player-on-facebook-wall)

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708233/share-html5-player-on-facebook-wall