# Will facebook provider videos to play in html5 mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

I have a player which plays in both flash and html5 mode, but when I share to facebook video plays in flash mode but not in flash. In HTML5 mode I am getting error like "Enable Flash"

Is facebook currently allowing videos to play in HTML5 mode? If yes, please help me how to share video to facebook in html5 mode

Comment: For now, **no**, for future, maybe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share HTML5 player on Facebook wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708233/share-html5-player-on-facebook-wall)